# Could not ping the port with the localhost

Tags: sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I have developed a TCP/IP client/server application in c#. After staring server I am able to ping with the actual IP and port for instance "ping 192.168.1.1 8001" but ping is not working with the localhost "ping 127.0.0.1 8001".

Can anyone explain why it is happening so?

Answer (score 2):

Because your server is now running on that specific IP available to that specific network interface, If you want the server to be available on both IP's run it on `0.0.0.0`